# How to get the distance matrix of a set of documents

Tags: matrix, text, cluster-analysis, distance

I'm trying to perform clustering over a set of documents using hierarchical clustering. However, I'm not sure how I can get the distance matrix of a set of documents. Anyone can help me on that?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. decide on what features to use
2. extract features
3. decide on similarity function to use
4. compute pairwise similarities
5. convert similarity to distance